# What is concurrent Signal?

Tags: continuous-signals

[I have come across with the term 'concurrent signal'](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25605504). What does this type of signal means?  What are it's importance?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! Can you please give an example of where this term is used?

Comment: @peter-k in the hyper linked article, I saw the term. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25605504. Seems like it is related to biomedical signals. ECG and PCG are called as concurrent. But why they are called so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concurrent signal is not a particular kind of signal, in the paper is written that ECG signal of fetus is weaker than concurrent signals, for example mother's ECG, that is one of the concurrent signals. Basically concurrent signals are called in this way because they are occuring simultaneously.